# What's the difference of mvn spring-boot:run and Application.main()

Tags: spring-boot

I just want to know is there any difference between I start a spring boot application with :

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

and

```
java -jar target/the-packaged-file.war (Or in IDE, right click and run java application)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great question.

We intend that there's no difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and running your app from your IDE. Both are starting a main class using the classpath of the project. The latter is strongly recommended when you're working on your app: if you run your app from your IDE you'll get all the nice features such as debugging and devtools. The former is used when you need a standard way to run the app on the command-line. The maven plugin can also start your app before the integration-test phase (see the `start` goal of the Maven/Gradle plugin). If you use the build to filter some resources, your IDE should be aware of that otherwise some data may not be filtered when you start the app from the IDE.

`java -jar yourapp.jar` is running on the final artifact. Spring Boot takes care of building the classpath of the application. Filtered resources are stored in the jar. But in the end, it is meant to do the exact same thing.

Now your question has `war` in it. You can't expect the regular `war` callback to apply to something that is ran as a main class. Having said that, Spring Boot does its best to give you all the tools to make that consistent. A `war` that is started from an running servlet container won't be initialized from the main method but a servlet initializer. You have a way however to share the initialization code so that it's consistent. The run goal of the plugin will add `src/main/webapp` so that those files are served as well.

TL;DR if you're looking for a consistent story across all environments, don't use war packaging.

Comment: I got the template error:
_Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers_

When I run the app with `java -jar target/myApp.jar` and try access a not valid url,
but when I run with `mvn spring-boot:run` my template error.html works normally.

Anyone knows why? Tanks

Comment: Please ask your own question, comments are not meant for that.

Comment: I have an application that behaves differently when I run it on STS using "Run As - Spring Boot App" vs running it on command line using "bootRun" or using "java -jar". What could be the difference ? Specically, when I run using bootRun, it doesn't make use of Spring Session.It uses Tomcat's session management. While running on STS, it does use Spring Session.

Comment: Did you type this all from your head?

Comment: I compared the target to launch with maven (mvn spring-boot:run) and the jar file for launch with jar( java -jar *.jar). Both include classpath,lib,config and the same. I didn't see any difference.